# Redirection set for folder in Classic ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic, redirect

I have classic asp website which not usable hence I wanted to redirect all requested URL to new website. But I do not have access to IIS manager, Is there any way to set 301 redirection from FTP client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving this as *web.config* and place it in the root dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.newsite.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If you cannot manage the site in IIS but can change the files replace them all with

```
<%
Response.Status = "301 Redirect"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://new.com/foo"
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually for files I am using the same thing to redirect permanent. I just wanted to know that if there any way like I just write one rule (like .htaccess in php) and redirect all files in particular folder without use of IIS manager ?